# Batch-convert lit -> txt

Tags: windows, conversion, ebook, parsing

Is there a tool for Windows to batch-convert a folder of `.lit` files to a different format, preferably plain-text?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: I'm looking for a Windows based app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) does most ebook related conversions including this one.

There is also [ConvertLit](http://www.convertlit.com/index.php) which is an executable that expands one .lit file but can be wrapped in a batch script.

Both work on most OSs

Answer (score 0):

ABC **Amber LIT Converter** is an freeware utility which converts your LIT (Microsoft Reader) files to any format you wish (PDF, HTML, CHM, RTF, HLP, DOC, and many more) easily and quickly.
The software supports a batch conversion, a run from command line, more than 50 languages. Batch conversion ability allows you to convert a unlimited number of LIT files at a time.

[ABC Amber](http://www.processtext.com/abclit.html)